Troubleshooting MySQL Connectivity in XAMPP
Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
11:08:27  [mysql]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
11:08:27  [mysql]   improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
11:08:27  [mysql]   Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
11:08:27  [mysql]   the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
11:08:27  [mysql]   If you need more help, copy and post this
11:08:27  [mysql]   entire log window on the forums

when starting the mysql in xampp , that gives this error

The reason of connectivity problems is that your server fails to start. You can press the Logs button to view error logs and check the Windows Event Viewer for more clues.
